# Extension of some operator formula

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be some complex Hilbert space. It was shown in many references that for some $0<r<1,$ we have

\begin{equation}
A^r = \frac{\sin(\pi r)}{\pi} \int_0^\infty s^{r-1}A(s+A)^{-1}ds,
\end{equation} 
for every normal bounded operator $A\in \mathcal{L}(H) $  with spectrum 
$$\sigma(A) \subset \Gamma:= \{z\in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\},\quad -\pi< Arg(z)<\pi\}.$$
Let now $A_0$ be bounded normal with spectrum $\sigma(A_0) \in \Gamma.$ 
Can we find $\delta >0$ such that the above formula is still true on 
$$B(A_0, \delta):= \{A \quad\text{is bounded  in}\quad \mathcal{L}(H), \|A_0-A\|\leq \delta\}?$$
It looks like a perturbation result. That's why I tried to find some useful hint [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kato1.pdf)... 
Thank you for any further hint.

Comment: This is derived using a contour integral so I'd expect it to fail if the perturbation makes the spectrum cross the contour.

Comment: Is there a perturbation which doesn't make the spectrum cross the contour?

Comment: For symmetric operators there is Thm. 4.10, p.291 of Kato.

Comment: In Page 286, he concludes that the above formula is true for the strictly "m-accretive" operators (see page 279 for the definition). A special case for such operators is the normal bounded operators whose spectrum in $\Gamma.$ The question now is: Could we do a perturbation by bounded operators on (3.38- p279) ?

Comment: You still need to know that the spectrum remains in the right half plane, which depends on the specific operators you are dealing with. I'm not sure what you mean by "do a perturbation". Usually that means we have an exact solution for some operator and want to calculate (or estimate) the solution for "nearby" operators.

Comment: Here is a more specific formulation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438834/perturbation-by-bounded-operators

Comment: Sorry I meant p 291.