# Perturbation by bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

Let $H$  be a complex Hilbert space. Denote $\mathcal{L}(H)$ the space of linear bounded operators on $H$ into $H.$ Let $N \in \mathcal{L}(H) $ be normal ($N^* N =NN^*$) such that $\sigma(N) \subset \Gamma := \{z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}, -\pi /2<Arg(z) <\pi/2 \}.$ It is clear that there exists  $C>0$ such that 
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
(N+\lambda)^{-1} \in \mathcal{L}(H)  \quad \text{and} \quad \|(N+\lambda)^{-1}\| < \frac{C}{Re(\lambda)} \forall \lambda \in \Gamma.
\end{equation}

Is it possible to find  $\delta >0$ such that  (1) is still true  for every $E \in \{A \in \mathcal{L}(H), \|N-A\| <\delta \}.$

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this indeed holds for a normal operator. In fact, since $\sigma(N)$ is closed bounded, whence compact, the real part attains a minimum on $\sigma(N)\in \Gamma$, so we have: ${\rm Re\;} z \geq \alpha>0$ for all $z\in \sigma(N)$.

For a normal operator, its norm is the same as the spectral radius, so when ${\rm Re\;} \lambda \geq 0$, $(\lambda+N)$ is invertible and its inverse $A=(\lambda+N)^{-1}$ verifies:
$$ \| A \| = \frac{1}{{\rm dist}(-\lambda,\sigma(N))} \leq \frac{1}{\alpha + {\rm Re\;} \lambda }\leq \frac{1}{\alpha} $$
Let $0<\delta<\alpha$. Whenever $\|U\|\leq  \delta$ we see that $(\lambda+N+U)= (\lambda+N)(I+(\lambda+N)^{-1} U)$ is invertible by a von Neumann series and we have the wanted bound:
 $$\|(\lambda+N+U)^{-1} \| = \|(I - A \;U + (A\; U)^2 - \cdots) A \| \leq \left(\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\delta^n}{\alpha^n} \right) \frac{1}{\alpha+{\rm Re\; } \lambda} \leq \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\delta}   \frac{1}{{\rm Re\; } \lambda}$$

Comment: Thank you. I was bit close to this nice answer. In fact, operators satisfying (1) are called in Kato's Perturbation Theory for linear operators:  strictly "accretive" operators.

Comment: You are welcome. A funny thing is that the constant $C$ is one for normal operators, but this you destroy by adding a perturbation.